# is it possible to hang a few web sites in one role at a port of Azure?

Tags: azure, port, azure-web-roles

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433110.aspx

```
 <Site name="ClientService" physicalDirectory="..\qwer.ClientService">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="ClientService" endpointName="EndpointClientService" hostHeader="ClientService.tsasdc.com" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
```

error

```
Error   1   The same local port '80' is assigned to input endpoints EndpointImageService and Endpoint1 in role qwer.Web.    C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\prohect\src\qwer.Azure\ServiceDefinition.csdef   1   1   qwer.Azure
```

Comment: It would be helpful to revise this question, to actually be a question.

Answer (score 1):

You must use one and the same EndPoint for all the sites you need. That is the need for defining the "hostHeader" in each Binding. For example, if you want a port 80 HTTP endpoint - you may have only one endpoint per Hosted Service. And you just map all your sites to the same endpoint.

Endpoint1 is predefined HTTP input endpoint on port 80 when you have Web Role. You can either rename it to something more meaningful, or just use it for your second site, and never create second input endpoint on HTTP protocol and port 80.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a few web sites, but they each have to point to their own unique port.  If you had multiple on the same port, it wouldn't know which one to send the request to.

Comment: That is not quite correct! That is where the **hostHeader** comes to place! You may read more about binding in IIS here: http://bit.ly/98AdNM

Answer (score 0):

both of your sites should have the same endpoint name. 
you got site with endpoint name Endpoint1;
the second site ( with the physicalDirectory attr) should go to the same endpoint with a hostHeader you already put.

```
<Sites>
  <Site name="Web">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
  <Site name="Web2" physicalDirectory="XXX">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" hostHeader="YOUR HOST HEADER" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
</Sites>
<Endpoints>
  <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />
</Endpoints>`
```